# How to use Javascript to make several rows in an HTML table invisible

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML table and there are several rows in that table that I want to toggle to either be visible or invisible as a group. Since I can't simply put a `<div>` around them, what would be a good way to 'group' them together.

Comment: The multiple tbody solution(s) are the most semantic, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

try making your html in such a way you can hide/visible and apply your css/js.

```
<table>
        <tr class="visible"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="visible"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="hidden"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="visible"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="visible"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="hidden"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="visible"><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group them in separate `<tbody>` elements *(since you can't use `<div>` elements, as you stated)*.

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tbody>
        <!-- some rows to group -->
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <!-- some rows to group -->
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <!-- some rows to group -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then select the tbody you want.

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytable");

table.tBodies[1].style.display="none";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the tbody tag. You can set the id attribute on it.

> tbody id="customer1"

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Customer</th><th>Order</th><th>Month</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="customer1">
        <tr><td>Customer 1</td><td>#1</td><td>January</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 1</td><td>#2</td><td>April</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 1</td><td>#3</td><td>March</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="customer2">
        <tr><td>Customer 2</td><td>#1</td><td>January</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 2</td><td>#2</td><td>April</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 2</td><td>#3</td><td>March</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="customer3">
        <tr><td>Customer 3</td><td>#1</td><td>January</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 3</td><td>#2</td><td>April</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Customer 3</td><td>#3</td><td>March</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then with JQuery you can easily hide/show.

Comment: yeah you're right, but the question is more about "grouping" the element in html than "hiding" them with js

Answer (score 0):

Place a common class on the rows which you want to group. than work on that like

or you have some set of rules for visible or hidden, rows group you can simple use css + javascript like

## HTML

```
<table id="myGroupTab">
    <tr class="group1"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr class="group1"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr class="group2"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr class="group2"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr class="group1"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
```

you can write some css rules like

## CSS

```
#myGroupTab.showGrp1 .group1{ display:block;}
#myGroupTab.showGrp1 .group2{ display:none;}

#myGroupTab.showGrp2 .group1{ display:none;}
#myGroupTab.showGrp2 .group2{ display:block;}
```

You can use Javascript like

## JS

```
document.getElementById('myGroupTab').className = "showGrp1"; //To Show Only tr.group1
document.getElementById('myGroupTab').className = "showGrp2"; //To Show Only tr.group2
```

Its even simple to make display none or block applying a class on parent, instead of looping every tr...

Or by jQuery you can achieve this, make them visible or hidden using jQuery.

```
$("tr.group1").hide() or  $("tr.group2").show()
```

@user1689607 solution using multiple tbody(s) in table is also a good solution.

Comment: @epascarello, Yes there is no jQuery tag in question.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a jQuery solution to you. Provide all of your `<tr>` tags a common class and a unique id (for individual selection). Then you can use jQuery to grab them.

```
$('tr .commonClass').css("display", "none");
```

You could also just swap classes with the individual ids

```
$('#someTR').removeClass("visibleClass");
$('#someTR').addClass("invisibleClass");
```

*Note:* For the record I prefer @Yograj Gupta's method, but he beat me to the punch posting.

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AC9wf/)

```
<table>
        <tr class="show"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="show"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="hide"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="show"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="show"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="hide"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="show"><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var trGroup = document.getElementsByClassName("hide");
for(var k=0; k < trGroup.length; k++){
     trGroup[k].style.display = "none";
}
```